# How to calculate a sum with simple for function in excel

Tags: excel, loops, for-loop, sum

I want to sum with many cells like this:
`C23 = SUM( for i = 2 to 22: $Ai/$Bi*Ci)`
and do it with C, D, E, F, ... (`..*Di`, `..*Ei`, etc)

Comment: `=SUM(A2:A22)`?

Comment: Or maybe `=A2:A22/B2:B22*C2:C22` which will give you a spilled range result.  Or maybe `=SUM(A2:A22/B2:B22*C2:C22)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

AS of Office 365 you can use:

`=SUM(A2:A22/(B2:B22*C2:C22))`

When using an older Excel Version use:

`={SUM(A2:A22/(B2:B22*C2:C22))}`

The `{}`-Bracktes indicate, that this is an array formula. That means, you don't have to type them, but you need to enter the formula with `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter` instead of the normal `Enter`.

Comment: Unless  you've got O365 - the formula will calculate without the `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter` part.

Answer (score 0):

For MS365 User which can natively handle array:
=SUM($A$2:$A$22/($B$2:$B$22*$C$2:$C$22))
Confirm with Enter

For Non MS365 User:

=SUM($A$2:$A$22/($B$2:$B$22*$C$2:$C$22))

Confirm with Control Shift Enter